# Using the logic:iterate tag with Struts 1

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-1

I am using Struts 1 framework and i have a query regarding the `logic:iterate` tag.

I have a collection object which stores a list of string objects,
i.e `Collection(List(String)) c = new ArraList(List(String))()`

I am setting the collection object on request scope to be used in my jsp.

Can any one guide me on how to use the `logic:iterate` tag?

Comment: You can also search the documentation anytime http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/logic/iterate.html having a go yourself first I think will also improve your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
<logic:iterate id="myList" name="yourCollectionInTheRequest">
    <logic:iterate id="myString" name="myList">
        <bean:write name="myString">
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: for example if myString returns in Block letters, is that possible to make it that in small letters. Sorry to ask this question here,